# Updating X,Y,Z floats and specific While Loop Scenario C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop

I have 2 problems I want to get through.

1st problem. Changing X,Y,Z movement and updating it.

I have a driving mechanic in my game where if the user presses wasd the car moves. The problem is that I want the speed to be reduced from 15f to 5f when S(backwards) is pressed and held until released.

Here is my code below of my player script. 
**Please refer to void playerwalk() and backwards motion()**

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{

public float speed;

private Rigidbody rb;

private int count;

public Text countText;



// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    SetCountText();
}

void playerWalk()
{
    var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 75f;
    var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 15f;

    transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
    transform.Translate(0, 0, -z);

}

void backwardMotion()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 5f;
    }
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Collectable"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText();
    }
}

void SetCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    backwardMotion();
    playerWalk();

}
}
```

This currently is not affecting anything and the void `backwardsmotion()` seems to have no effect. 
Do I need a while loop? 
What is the syntax for do until in C#?

2nd Problem : Do until loop?

To those of you who haven't seen my recent posts, I also have a flashlight mechanic on my car model where if you press L, the flashlights will turn on(toggle) and if you press S the backlights will as you reverse.

Here is my flashlight game mechanic code: 
**Please refer to Void switchoffLights()**

```
public class headLights : MonoBehaviour
{

public Light frontlights;
public Light frontlights2;
public Light frontlights3;
public Light frontlights4;
public Light backlights;
public Light backlights2;
public Light backlights3;
public Light backlights4;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    frontlights.enabled = !frontlights.enabled;
    frontlights2.enabled = !frontlights2.enabled;
    frontlights3.enabled = !frontlights3.enabled;
    frontlights4.enabled = !frontlights4.enabled;

}

void switchoffLight()
{

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
    {
        if (frontlights && frontlights2 && frontlights3 && frontlights4 != null)
        {
            frontlights.enabled = !frontlights.enabled;
            frontlights2.enabled = !frontlights2.enabled;
            frontlights3.enabled = !frontlights3.enabled;
            frontlights4.enabled = !frontlights4.enabled;

        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        if (backlights && backlights2 && backlights3 && backlights4 != null)
        {
            backlights.enabled = !backlights.enabled;
            backlights2.enabled = !backlights2.enabled;
            backlights3.enabled = !backlights3.enabled;
            backlights4.enabled = !backlights4.enabled;

        }
    }
}
```

}

However the backlights do not turn off when the S key is released.

I could not clearly understand what was going on with other codes and answers which is why I am asking here.

Thank you in advance! I am only just starting for my grade 10 programming class so please explain like you would to a younger person.

Comment: Please don't post multiple question at the same time. [edit] your question to cover only one problem, and [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) covering the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You are not applying any change to transform or rotation when pressing

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 5f;         
    }
```

// Where this z go ?????
        // Add this or whatever you want "transform.Translate(0, 0, -z);"

For Second question Use GetKeyUp() in another condition or use getkey in same condition

Answer (score 0):

### For the first question, you declared `var z` twice but they are actually individual values.

```
var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 15f; // playerWalk()
```

and

```
var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 5f; // backwardMotion()
```

refer to **two different variables** with the same name `z` but each **only live in the method it is declared in**. The `z` in `playerWalk()` and the `z` in `backwardMotion()` has nothing to do with each other. The `z` in `backwardMotion()` essentially serves no purpose as the variable is declared but never used anywhere in the method.

The correct way to achieve what you want will be:

```
void playerWalk()
{
    var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 75f;
    var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 15f;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        // If "S" is pressed, the z speed would be reduced to 5f.
        z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 5f; 
    }

    transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
    transform.Translate(0, 0, -z);
}
```

### For the second question, there are three way to get input: `Input.GetKeyDown`, `Input.GetKey` and `Input.GetKeyUp`.

`Input.GetKeyDown` is called only once on the frame you pressed the key.

`Input.GetKey` is called every frame the key is held down.

`Input.GetKeyUp` is called only once on the frame you released the key.

In your case, your car backlight would be turned on when it detects a `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)` but nothing lets it turn back off when it detects a release.

The solution would be to simply check for a release and turn off the headlight:

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S)) // Detects a release of "S" key
{
    if (backlights && backlights2 && backlights3 && backlights4)
    {
        backlights.enabled = false;
        backlights2.enabled = false;
        backlights3.enabled = false;
        backlights4.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me so much time trying to fix this problem, I can only imagine how many hours of fustration I would of been in if it wasn't for you.     Your guidelines and explanation are very clear and easy to understand. Enjo your weekend :)